# How to call an api containing array of strings through my react code

Tags: reactjs, axios

I need to call an api which consists of an array of string. I need to then publish the response from the api in a dropdown menu. Below is what the API holds that I need to call-

Sample api data - [“Leanne Graham”,”Ervin Howell”,”Patricia”]

Below sample code has the API which holds object information

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../styles/schema.css";
import Params1 from "../components/Params1";
import axios from 'axios';
import Select from "react-select";
class New extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleStoreprocSelection = this.handleStoreprocSelection.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      selectStoreprocOptions : [],
      id: "",
      name: '',
      itemSelected:false
    }
  }

  async getStoreProcOptions(){
    const resSchema = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users') --backend API call in object format
    const data = resSchema.data
  
    const options = data.map(d => ({
      "value" : d.id,
      "label" : d.name
    }))
    this.setState({selectStoreprocOptions: options})
  }

  handleStoreprocSelection(){
    // alert('You selected me!!')
    this.setState({itemSelected: true});
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // get all entities - GET
    this.getStoreProcOptions()

  }
  

  render() {

    const itemSelected = this.state.itemSelected;
    let param;
    if (itemSelected) {
      param = <Params1 />;
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
            <form id ="store-proc">
            <label>STORED PROCEDURE</label>
            <Select id="store-proc-select" options={this.state.selectStoreprocOptions} onChange={this.handleStoreprocSelection} /> --my dropdown
            </form>
            </div>
            {param}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default New;
```

Comment: Can you share with us, what you have done so far ? Or give us an example of your try

Comment: if you could post some minimal code to help us understand what you are trying to achieve, we could help you better

Answer (score 0):

1. You need a state, let's say an empty array.
2. You need to call that API, using some of the methods, for example browser built in **fetch** or 3rd party library **axios**.
3. Then you need to update your state with the response you will get from your API.
4. Finally use your state inside of your component and display whatever you want.

These are the steps you need to follow, if you needed some logic. Since you didn't provide any code, I assume you didn't know from where to start. If you share some code, will be possible to help more.

Answer (score 0):

are you using any library? because the plain HTML form select would be written in lower case `<select/>`, not `<Select/>`. if so, please state it out.

in plain HTML: the solution would be to `map` the array elements into `<option/>`. so, `selectStoreprocOptions` from `state`, as assigned here: `this.setState({selectStoreprocOptions: options})`.

inside `render`:

```
<select>
  {
    this.state.selectStoreprocOptions.map(selectStoreprocOption => (<option ..> .. </option>)
  }
</select>
```

**Edit:** Sorry, I've overseen the use of `react-select`. never used it, according to the API doc it looks good to me. have you checked that your state really contains an array with the expected objects?

probably ignore my post then, sorry again xD

Comment: Yes, I am using Select from react-select as mentioned in the import

Comment: oh sorry, I've overseen that one. I'll update the post.

Comment: The only issue is that with a different api which has the data in below format, above code does not work for me-   ["$G680301","AIM1","AIM2","B6435CUU","B6435DBS","B6435DBT","B6435DBU","BEFT","CC390","CICSIA"] can you please help?